# ASUS windows 8 desktop dual boot is not working

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

ASUS windows 8 desktop dual boot is not working -

After I download tbe ubuntu ISO file and burn onto a CD , and select the boot sequence priority as CD , it won't come up. Showing that

> load valid one into boot device.

Help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

This guide should be helpfull:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
have you tried the boot menu?
32bit will not boot with 'secure boot' enabled in the bios, if a system has a windows 8 sticker it has the option and is enabled

Answer (score 0):

The installer doesn’t recognize Windows 8 partition, so you can’t use the straight-forward install Ubuntu alongside with Windows option during setup.

Turn on the PC and boot into Windows 8. Create a new partition for Ubuntu installation.

If you don't know how create a partition within Windows, follow the steps toward the bottoms of this link. http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-createdelete-a-partition-in-windows-7/.

Once you do that, reboot to CD, though a USB mount is preferred as it is much quicker than the conventional CD/DVD method.

If you continue to have problems after creating a partition for it then I'd definitely try the USB approach, rule out any errors with your CD image.